# Dividing a particular column by 100 in Emacs

Tags: linux, bash, math, command-line, emacs

I'm trying to divide all the values of second column (Tide(cm)) by 100 in emacs. Can anyone kindly help me how can I do that from linux command prompt?

[Here is the screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQdXY.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: From the command prompt? So you want to use Emacs Lisp for scripting, invoking `emacs` with the `-batch` switch? And where do you expect the output? The question is not very clear.

Comment: Hi, I'm quiet new in in Linux operating system. So, what I'm trying to do is to write a one line command to include it in to a shell script since I'll have to modify similar types of files at 6 hours intervals. So, I want to write a command to divide the 2nd column of my text by 100 which is in centimeters to convert it into meter. I want to overwrite on the existing file. This one should be something like 'grep' but not sure how to do the arithmetic operations in that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use you shell, use perl instead of emacs:

given this file:

> cat new.txt
>   some header
>   don't care tide (care)  dc      dc      dc
>    0.00      17.873       5       bla     kuku
>    1.00      36.53        lkfj    kuku    42

`perl -p -e 's/(\s+\d+\.\d+\s+)(\d+.\d+)(.*)/$1.($2\/100).$3/e' new.txt`

> some header
>   don't care tide (care)  dc      dc      dc
>    0.00      0.17873      5       bla     kuku
>    1.00      0.3653       lkfj    kuku    42

Answer (score 0):

[image: how to use emacs org mode to divide the second column by 10]

how to use emacs org mode to divide the second column by 10

```
1) mark region

Col1 Col2 Col3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12

2) M-x, then org-table-create-or-convert-from-region
3) insert a horizontal line to seperate the column headers from the
   data by putting a: ‘|-‘ (without the quotes) one the line and hit
   the tab button

should look like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------+------+------|
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    4 |    5 |    6 |
|    7 |    8 |    9 |
|   10 |   11 |   12 |

4) org-table-eval-formula, but for whole column:
‘C-5 C-c =’
5) then type the formula as $2/10.0 so that the prompt looks like:
Column formula $2=$2/10.0

should look like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------+------+------|
|    1 |  0.2 |    3 |
|    4 |  0.5 |    6 |
|    7 |  0.8 |    9 |
|   10 |  1.1 |   12 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$2/10.0

there are a bunch of export options
```